# Tornado io_loop add_future callback not being called

Tags: python, callback, websocket, tornado

I'm working on a Tornado WebSocket server that does some asynchronous actions when a message is received.
I added a callback with io_loop.add_future to get notified when the function ends or if an exception is raised, but this callback is never called.

This is an example of what is happening:

```
import tornado
from tornado.httpclient import HTTPRequest
from tornado.web import Application
from tornado.websocket import websocket_connect
from tornado.testing import AsyncHTTPTestCase, gen_test

def message_processed_callback(*args, **kwargs):
    print 'Callback(args=%r, kwargs=%r)' % (args, kwargs)

class RealtimeHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def initialize(self):
        self.io_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()

    def on_message(self, message):
        future = self.on_some_message(message)
        print 'The future:', future
        self.io_loop.add_future(future, message_processed_callback)

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def on_some_message(self, message):
        print 'Before sleep'
        yield tornado.gen.sleep(3)
        print 'After sleep'
        self.write_message(message)

class ChatTestCase(AsyncHTTPTestCase):
    def get_app(self):
        return Application([
            ('/rt', RealtimeHandler),
        ])

    @gen_test
    def test_reply(self):
        request = HTTPRequest('ws://127.0.0.1:%d/rt' % self.get_http_port())
        ws = yield websocket_connect(request)

        ws.write_message('Hi')

        response = yield ws.read_message()
        print 'Response:', response
```

Executing this test results in:

```
Before sleep
The future: <tornado.concurrent.Future object at 0x4c01250>
[The sleep takes place here]
After sleep
Response: Hi
```

Comment: I managed to get the callback changing **self.io_loop.add_future(future, message_processed_callback)** by **future.add_done_callback(message_processed_callback)** but I thought this is what add_future was intended to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure isolation between tests, each test case runs with its own independent `IOLoop` - not `IOLoop.instance()`. The test's `IOLoop` can be accessed with `IOLoop.current()` (which should nearly always be used instead of `IOLoop.instance()`).

If you have a requirement to use `IOLoop.instance()` due to libraries outside your control, you can make the test use that `IOLoop` by overriding `AsyncTestCase.get_new_ioloop`.

Comment: As you said `add_future` only fails on tests, changing to `IOLoop.current()` solved the problem. The example I followed may be outdated and use `IOLoop.instance()` I see that documentation is correct.

Comment: As `IOLoop.add_future` and  `Future.add_done_callback` both gives the desired result, which is the correct way to do it?

Comment: `IOLoop.add_future` is better. For Futures created by Tornado, it doesn't matter much, but for Futures created by the concurrent.futures package, it guarantees that your callback runs on the IOLoop thread.